# Where Android stores bluetooth pairings/settings

Tags: settings, bluetooth

Settings like Wi-Fi are stored on

`[root]/data/misc/wifi/WifiConfigStore.xml`

What about bluetooth ?

Whre did they decide to hide it ?

Are they encrypted ?

**: |**

Thank you ahead

**Oreo** here, but the answer is probably universal

Answer (score 1):

Amazing how we find the answer only AFTER we post the question:

```
[root]/data/misc/
bluedroid/bt_config.conf
```

"Bluedroid"... Haha

Found this by digging the *Bluetooth Pairings* backups that Titanium does.

**Edit.:**
Careful not to confuse with bt_config.xml

This second file (xml) is full of garbage, in my case